# React-Routing When I type in urls they are not working but when I start from root i can access them

Tags: react-router, url-mapping

New to the react framework and trying to gather my wits about react-router.
Following a tutorial that uses hash history(which is deprecated), I am now using browser-history

code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory} from 'react-router';

import Bootstrap from './vendor/bootstrap-without-jquery.min';

import Archives from './pages/Archives';
import Featured from './pages/Featured';
import Layout from './pages/Layout';
import Settings from './pages/Settings';

const app = document.getElementById('app');
ReactDOM.render(
<Router history={browserHistory}>
  <Route path="/" component={Layout}>
    <IndexRoute path="/featured" component={Featured} />
    <Route path="archives/:article" name="archives" component={Archives}></Route>
    <Route path="settings" component={Settings}></Route>
</Route>
</Router>,
app);
```

this is my layout:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link, Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router';

export default class Layout extends React.Component{
navigate(){
    browserHistory.push("/");
}

render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <h1>KillerNews.net</h1>
            {this.props.children}
            <Link to="archives" class="btn btn-info">archives</Link>
            <Link to="settings" class="btn btn-info">settings</Link>
            <button onClick={this.navigate.bind(this)}>featured</button>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I cannot type in the urls, I can only access them when I start from root. I dont have any paths set up on server side just running webpack,babel and react.

Comment: Ok I see when i use hashHistory I can type in my address bar(url's url params) but when I use browserHistory I get 404's. Do I need to hook up server in order to establish an endpoint for these urls to use browserHistory or am I missing something here

Comment: No need realized I have to map urls on backend  .....FEELING LIKE A REEL NOOB RIGHT NOW!!!